# Parallel LSTMs each working on diffrent part of the input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

What is the change needed to be done with this code to get a model like in the picture?

```
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(self.timestamps, len(columns)), activation=keras.activations.tanh,
                       recurrent_activation=keras.activations.tanh))
        model.add(Dense(6, activation=keras.activations.tanh))
        model.summary()
        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop())
```

[image: stdScore]

For example, if the batch `input` for this model is of shape (10,30,6) then i want  `input[:,:15,:]` to flow into the left LSTM and `input[:,15:,:]` to flow to the right LSTM. How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest using the [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). It tends to simplify model definitions.

If you want to define two inputs to the model, you can define your model like this:

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, concatenate, Dense
from keras.models import Model

input_1 = Input(shape=(15, 6), name='input_1')
input_2 = Input(shape=(15, 6), name='input_2')
lstm1 = LSTM(256, name='lstm1')(input_1)
lstm2 = LSTM(256, name='lstm2')(input_2)
concat = concatenate([lstm1, lstm2]) 
output = Dense(6, activation='tanh', name='dense')(concat)
model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
```

If you don't want to specify multiple inputs, you can just use a `Lambda` layer to split the inputs:

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, concatenate, Dense, Lambda
from keras.models import Model

input_ = Input(shape=(30, 6), name='input')
input_1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :15, :])(input)
input_2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 15:, :])(input)
lstm1 = LSTM(256, name='lstm1')(input_1)
lstm2 = LSTM(256, name='lstm2')(input_2)
concat = concatenate([lstm1, lstm2]) 
output = Dense(6, activation='tanh', name='dense')(concat)
model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=output)
```

You would call the `fit` function as follows for each example, respectively:

---

Multiple Inputs:

`model.fit(x=[input_1, input_2], y=y)`

OR

`model.fit(x={'input_1': input_1, 'input_2': input_2}, y=y)`

---

Single Input:

`model.fit(x=input_, y=y)`

Comment: Thanks, can you show me how you call fit for the first example?

Comment: Just added that part. Plus another possible way to input that is more verbose.